# 特定の文字列をファイル名に含むものだけを探して別フォルダにコピーしたい

Tags: windows, batch-file

バッチファイルでの動作を考えています。
カレントディレクトリ(target)からサブディレクトリの階層はバラバラですが「test」とファイル名に含まれたファイルを探して、目標のディレクトリ(dest)にファイルのみをコピーをしたいです。

エラースキップやログを残したいため、ファイルのコピーにはrobocopyを利用したいと思っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: "test とタイトルが入った" は、ファイル名ではなく「ファイルの中に記述された」という意味でしょうか。

Comment: ファイル名になります。
例えばtest_1.xlsxやxxx_test_2020.txtなどのファイルがあれば、タイトルにtestと入っておりますので、抽出対象になります。
この時、ディレクトリ構造ごとコピーするのではなく、ファイルのみコピーしたいと思っています。

Comment: カレントとサブフォルダのファイル名が同じ場合は、どのような扱いとなるでしょうか？コピー先にファイルのみがコピーされるとのことでお聞きしました。

Comment: 基本的に重複したファイル名は無い運用を考えておりますが、例えばカレントの方にtest.txtというファイルがあって先にdistフォルダにコピーされた場合、サブフォルダにあるtest.txtはスキップする想定でおります。

Comment: ただし、スキップが難しい場合、上書きや、ファイルのリネーム（test_コピー1.txtなど）でも構いません。

Comment: 質問に直接関わるような条件は、[編集] から追記しておくとより回答が付きやすくなります。 / 今回の場合は「タイトルに入った」より「ファイル名に含まれた」と明記してしまった方がよさそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。編集で変更しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

あまりスッキリした方法ではないですが、以下のコマンドでどうでしょうか。
サブディレクトリのコピーを行ってから、カレントのコピーをしています。

```
 cd [FromDir]
 for /d %i in (*) do robocopy %i [ToDir] *test* 
 robocopy [FromDir] [ToDir] *test*
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
希望通りの動きになりました。
ただし無知で大変申し訳ないのですが、コマンドプロンプトに一行づつ貼り付ければ正常に動きますが、batファイルにして実行するとうまく動きません。
原因は何でしょうか？

Comment: %→%%にしたらbatで動きました！

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Comment: すみません、コメント内容確認しました。動いてよかったです。

Answer (score 1):

以下の記事の応用で、`for`を利用すれば出来るでしょう。
[「指定ディレクトリ」内の「任意の階層」にある「指定ディレクトリ名」内にある全ファイルを抽出したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60797/26370)

こんな感じでしょうか。

```
for /r TargetDir %I in (*test*.*) do robocopy %~pI DestDir %~nxI
```

必要があればrobocopyコマンド指定の最後にファイル選択やログ出力先など細かい指定のオプションを追加してください。
ただし、フォルダ名やファイル名に空白が含まれていると、おかしなことが発生しそうなので、その辺は注意するか工夫してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ 希望通りの動きになりました。下にご回答いただいた方にも同じ質問をしましたが、 コマンドプロンプトに一行づつ貼り付ければ正常に動きますが、batファイルにして実行するとうまく動きません。 原因は何でしょうか？

Comment: それは割と一般的な仕様でバッチファイル内では％Iとかは％％Iにしなければならないというものですね。%~pIも%%~pIとかではないかな。

Comment: うまく動きました！
ありがとうございました。感謝感謝です(^^)

Comment: ちなみにこんな記事です。[.bat（バッチファイル）のforコマンド解説。](https://qiita.com/plcherrim/items/67be34bab1fdf3fb87f9)